# $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)\ne0$. Show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty f \left( \frac{1}{n \ln n} \right)$ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$,  $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)\ne 0$.
>
> Show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty f \left( \frac{1}{n \ln n} \right)$ diverges.

I can't figure out how the information about the derivative helps me. Hint, please?

Comment: Is $f$ continuously differentiable on the whole interval, or only differentiable in $0$?

Comment: What regularity constraints are fulfilled by $f$? Is is a differentiable function over $[-1,1]$, a $C^1$ function over $[-1,1]$ or what else?

Comment: I wrote the question exactly as it was presented to me. So all we know is what the question says.

Comment: Anyway, $$\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k\log k}$$ is divergent by Cauchy's condensation test and $$ f\left(\frac{1}{k \log k}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{k \log k}\right) - f(0) = \frac{f'(\xi)}{k\log k} $$ with $\xi\in\left(0,\frac{1}{k\log k}\right)$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: But I do not think that $f'(0)=f(0)=0$ only is enough to conclude something about the divergence of $\sum_{k\geq 2}f\left(\frac{1}{k\log k}\right).$ We may just define $f\left(\frac{1}{k\log k}\right)=\frac{1}{k^2}$ then define $f$ at the other points of $[-1,1]$ in such a way that $f'(0)=0=f(0)$.

Comment: But you can't necessarily use Lagrange's theorem. And notice that I edited the question, it says $f'(0) \not = 0$.

Comment: Nothing prevents me from using Lagrange's theorem, if $f$ is differentiable over $[-1,1]$. The point is that if $f$ is differentiable but not $C^1$, the claim might not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $f'(0)=k>0.$ That is,

$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta >0: 0<x<\delta \implies \frac{f(x)}{x}>k-\epsilon.$$ Thus, for $\epsilon=k/2$ we have

$$\exists \delta >0: 0<x<\delta \implies \frac{f(x)}{x}>k/2.$$ Thus, for $n$ big enough we have

$$f\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)\ge \frac k{2 n\log n}.$$ Thus the series is not convergent. We can argue in a similar way if $f'(0)=k<0.$

Comment: (+1) Way more convincing.

Comment: I like this answer, and the first-principles approach seems very appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 1):

By definition
$$
0\neq f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{f(a_n)}{a_n}
$$

which is true for every sequence $(a_n)_n\subset[-1,1]$ converging to $0$.

Thus let's take 
$$
a_n:=\frac1{n\log n}
$$
from which you have that
$$
f\left(\frac1{n\log n}\right)\sim\frac1{n\log n}\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;n\to+\infty
$$
and you can conclude since $\sum_n\frac1{n\log n}$ diverges by Cauchy condensation criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is differentiable at $0$, we know that $f$ is continuous at $0$. So for a small enough $\delta$, we have that $f$ does not change sign on $[0, \delta]$. Suppose without loss of generality that $f$ is positive on $[0,\delta]$.

Then we apply the standard limit comparison test, and compare our sum to $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$. Then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n \ln n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n \ln n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n \ln n}\right) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n \ln n} - 0} = f'(0) \neq 0.$$

So the sum $\sum f(\frac{1}{n \ln n})$ behaves like the sum $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$, and therefore diverges.

---

[Thank you to Jack D'Aurizio for pointing out an error, and then to Hetebrij for indicating how to correct that error]

Comment: We do not know that $f'$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of zero, then why $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f'\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right) = f'(0)$$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah yes. You're right. Whoops.

Comment: Since $f(0) = 0$, your limit is simply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ f( \frac{1}{n \ln n}) - f(0) }{ \frac{1}{n \ln n} - 0}$, which is the derivative at $0$.

Comment: @Hetebrij You're right! Thank you for that insight

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=-x^2$ otherwise?
$f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but $f$ changes its sign infinity many times. Although, $f'(0)=0$, so it does not satisfy the question conditions.